# Cardinality of the set $\mathbb{Z}_{26}^5$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to compute the unicity for a Vigenère cipher with $m=5$ to compute this I need the sizes(cardinality) of the plaintext space and key space they are the sets $\mathbb{Z}_{26}^5$. Integers modulo 26 in a bracket to the power of 5. Could someone advise me how to compute this cardinality?

Many thanks!

Comment: $26^5=11881376$

Comment: Just 26^5? Thank you I suppose that would make sense since the elements run from [0]-[25]

Answer (score 1):

*Posted to resolve this question's "Unanswered" status.*

---

As it was phrased in the comments:

> $26^5 = 118813766$

which "would make sense since the elements run from [0]-[25]".